# What happens if i disable some module in OctoberCMS?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, octobercms

First, I'm new in Symfony/Laravel/October apps.

I'm using a lot of themes/plugins/components features (and Laravel purely) and I want to known what (**technically**) will happen when i disable *"System"*, *"Backend"* and/or *"Cms"* modules in `config/cms.php`.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Determines which modules to load
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specify which modules should be registered when using the application.
|
*/

'loadModules' => ['System', 'Backend', 'Cms'],
```

Answer (score 0):

What will happen, "technically" is that module will be disabled and won't load. If you disable "System" nothing will work because both of those other modules depend on it, however if you had no need for the Cms module (i.e. you're just using October for its backend and a plugin for handling an API) then you could do that.